# Create secondary axis for dataframe using pandas, python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

Here is the example how dataframe is converted into column-stacked-chart. The result of this code is : [image: here] What I want now is to add line to this chart. For that line I want to have additional secondary y axis. I don't wanna use matplotlib, because this library, as I found, is only for displaying the data and I want to save the data in excel file. I want to add secondary y axis using pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
from vincent.colors import brews

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Some sample data to plot.
    farm_1 = {'apples': 10, 'berries': 32, 'squash': 21, 'melons': 13, 'corn': 18}
    farm_2 = {'apples': 15, 'berries': 43, 'squash': 17, 'melons': 10, 'corn': 22}
    farm_3 = {'apples': 6, 'berries': 24, 'squash': 22, 'melons': 16, 'corn': 30}
    farm_4 = {'apples': 12, 'berries': 30, 'squash': 15, 'melons': 9, 'corn': 15}

    data = [farm_1, farm_2, farm_3, farm_4]
    index = ['Farm 1', 'Farm 2', 'Farm 3', 'Farm 4']

    # Create a Pandas dataframe from the data.
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index)

    # Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
    excel_file = 'C:/Users/gegij/Desktop/stacked_column_farms.xlsx'
    sheet_name = 'Sheet1'

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file, engine='xlsxwriter')
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name)

    # Access the XlsxWriter workbook and worksheet objects from the dataframe.
    workbook = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets[sheet_name]

    # Create a chart object.
    chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'column', 'subtype': 'stacked'})

    # Configure the series of the chart from the dataframe data.
    for col_num in range(1, len(farm_1) + 1):
        chart.add_series({
            'name':       ['Sheet1', 0, col_num],
            'categories': ['Sheet1', 1, 0, 4, 0],
            'values':     ['Sheet1', 1, col_num, 4, col_num],
            'fill':       {'color': brews['Pastel1'][col_num - 1]},
            'gap':        20,
        })

    # Configure the chart axes.
    chart.set_x_axis({'name': 'Total Produce'})
    chart.set_y_axis({'name': 'Farms', 'major_gridlines': {'visible': False}})

    # Insert the chart into the worksheet.
    worksheet.insert_chart('H2', chart)

    # Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
    writer.save()
```

Comment: What data in this example do you want to use for the secondary axis?

Comment: Well, actually it doesn't matter in this example. I just wanna find out how can I create secondary y axis for future data. Let's say I want line for the average quantity of fruits. For first farm for example (10 + 32 + 21 + 13 + 18) / 5. This should be simple and understandable example for that line.

Comment: In that case take a look at the chart `y2_axis()` method in XlsxWriter: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_charts.html#chart-secondary-axes

Comment: Thanks, it worked. One more question. Can I create multiple y axis? Now I've created default and secondary, can I add third for example?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Only 1 primary and 1 secondary axis are supported.

Comment: Well, okay. Thanks.